# HashMap: get arraylist to be a set of key or value

Tags: java

I have two arraylists A1, A2. Each element of A1 would be the key and each element of A2 the corresponding value. So the solution that I found is looping on A1 ( A1 and A2 have the same size) making hashmap.add(A1[i],A2[i]) but is there a way to directly send the key value pairs as two sets? I want to avoid loops it is going to slow my code..Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of key value pairs.  The only way to take that list and add it into the `Hashmap` is to iterate the list.  If you had your key value pairs stored in some other type of `Map` object then you could use the `Hashmap` constructor `HashMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)` but not with your `ArrayList`.

Don't fear the iteration in your code if it is the right approach.  Remember [Polya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It):  Find a solution, then see if you can find a better solution.

Comment: And of course that constructor would simply iterate through the parameter map as well.

Answer (score 5):

"I want to avoid loops it is going to slow my code." Anytime code does anything, it slows down your code. The key is to avoid doing things you don't need to do. Something needs to iterate through your lists.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be able to control the order in which you insert the items into the arrays, and you can do so in sorted order, you may not need the `HashMap` after all. While the hashed lookup will exhibit *amortized constant time*, you can get lookup in *O(log n)* time with [*binary search*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) over a sorted random-access sequence like an array. Function [`Arrays#binarySearch()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29) allows you to figure out which element, if any, matches your key in the first array and, given that position, you could the access the corresponding value in the parallel array.

This approach is most beneficial when you build up the data only once and look up entries frequently, and don't do any subsequent adding or removing of entries.

Comment: You could even wrap that in your very own Map implementation, which could have a 2 List argument constructor :)

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that you'd probably want to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` for all the mutating methods, including those exposed by iterators.

Comment: Hi seh, well that's the problem, I can't control the order in which I insert the items into the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would be able to avoid the iteration to insert the data into arrays doing it directly into the hashmap.

Good luck!

Comment: yes I finally found a way to make my code allow me doing that! :)